# Excel wrapping text when it doesn't need to

Tags: microsoft-excel

I noticed in Excel that when I type in a cell and the text almost becomes larger than the cell width, excel adds a blank line to the cell when wrap text is on. This is a surprise to me as the cell shouldn't be wrapping text, because it can contain the text quite well. What is the mechanism behind this and can this be prevented?

Before I change the width: 
[image: Before changing width]

If I change the width by right clicking on the column and changing the width there, I can change it indefinitely without it reverting back to one row. If I change it by dragging it, I can also do it indefinitely. The only that helps is stand after the last te and pressing delete.

Comment: How much do you need to widen the column to remove the new line? Are you sure that there aren't trailing blanks in the cell and it is these that are wrapping to the new line? Perhaps you could [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1401017/edit) your question to add an image of a problem cell.

Comment: What happens if you zoom in/out? Excel's screen rendering of type is notoriously imprecise

Comment: You also need to verify there is nothing in the adjacent cell. If Excel thinks there's something to the right of your "test test test te" cell, it won't continue the string. You can check by entering `=CODE(Cell to test)` and drag down. If anything other than #VALUE! shows, there's something in that cell.

Comment: it is not even wrapping text, otherwise "st" would have appeared in the next line after "Te". And I think Excel doesn't breaks word for wrapping, it changes line at white space.